# IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync popup hangs before asking email and password

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to use MSAL in C# to get an access token and the popup asking for the username and password hangs.  When I call IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync, a popup used to have the email address and password.  Now, the popup is empty except for "Connecting to a service" in the title bar and spinning dots in the middle.  I've let it sit for several minutes without any change before closing the window and killing my app.  The issue seems to be specific to my machine since others on my team can use the same code and get a populated popup.  Since I haven't entered an email address or password, I don't think any network communication has started.

Here's a snippet of code that's making the specific call:

```
if (GraphClientHelper.IdentityClientApp == null)
{
    GraphClientHelper.IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(GraphClientHelper.MsaClientId);
}

GraphClientHelper.IdentityClientApp.UserTokenCache.Clear(GraphClientHelper.MsaClientId);
AuthenticationResult authResult = await GraphClientHelper.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);

MyUser = authResult.User;
MyToken = authResult.Token;
MyExpiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
```

I'm writing a UWP app in C# using VS2017.  My project uses the version 1.0.304142221-alpha of the NuGet Microsoft.Identity.Client package.

Comment: Try downloading and running a [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) trace.  You can use this to see if the request is ever being initiated or if it is a network connectivity issue.

Comment: Fiddler doesn't capture any information during this time.  Are there ETW events I could enable?  I found that if I let the popup sit for ~90 seconds, it eventually gets filled in and asks for my username/password.  Fiddler doesn't capture any data until after I finish entering my username/password and give the app permission to access my account.

Comment: That's quite interesting, but I don't think this is related to MSAL.  It sounds like it may be an issue of the network you're connected to that may have some kind of firewall or weird routing that's causing it to hang for a bit. I don't think there's anyway to configure Fiddler to view ETW events, it's meant to capture web HTTP requests.

Comment: I would try the computer on another network if this is possible and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You should try with latest packages in MyGet feed at https://www.myget.org/feed/aad-clients-nightly/package/nuget/Microsoft.Identity.Client